# HttpWebRequest invalid contentlength

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, content-length

I need to get content length in order to tell my app where the buffer ends. The problem is that httpwebresponse.ContentLength returns -1 even though Content-Length header is presented in response.

Then I though I'm going to read the actual header to find out the length. The Content-Length returned by the page I'm testing on is 1646. An HTTP sniffer claims that I received 1900 bytes, so I assume the difference are the header length. Then I copied the whole body from response and pasted it into online strlen site and the body size is actually 1850!!

How is this possible? Why does response return invalid content-length and why does httpwebrequest.ContentLength returns -1? How can I calculate the actual response length before receiving the response itself?

EDIT:
This is the code I'm using to get the response:

```
                  using (System.IO.Stream responseStream = hwresponse.GetResponseStream())
                  {
                      using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                      {
                          int count = 0;
                          do
                          {
                              count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                              TCP_R.SendBytes(buffer);

                          } while (count != 0);

                      }
                  }

                  byte[] PACKET_END_IDENTIFIER = { 0x8, 0x01, 0x8, 0x1, 0x8 };
                  TCP_R.SendBytes(PACKET_END_IDENTIFIER);
                  TCP_R.Close();
```

I have a proxy server application that takes a request, sends it to another application (my client) client executes the request and using TCP_R class returns the result. When server gets response from client, it returns response back to browser.

Each time I do a request, I get all the data + extra garbage, here's an example:

```
<tag1><tag2><tag3> ag3>
```

ag3> is the garbage data, it's like the ending of buffer is cut off and added again. It apprears that the client responds with a valid response, the garbage data is added onDataRecieve event.. any tips? thanks!

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: No apology necessary. Now you know.

Comment: Maybe you should look at HttpWeb **Response** .ContentLength  ?

Comment: @L.B I actually wrote 'request' by accident, I was using response.ContentLength :p

Answer (score 7):

-1 isn't an invalid value of the `ContentLength` property. I assume you mean the `ContentLength` property of the *response* is -1... asking the *request* what the length is would be non-sensical. Even so, it's perfectly valid:

> The ContentLength property contains the value of the Content-Length header returned with the response. If the Content-Length header is not set in the response, ContentLength is set to the value -1.

If the body length is 1850, that suggests it's using [*chunked transfer encoding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). But that should be transparent to you - just keep reading from the response stream until the end. If you're using .NET 4, it's dead easy - just create a `MemoryStream` and use `Stream.CopyTo` to copy the data to that `MemoryStream`.

Comment: Thanks! The problem I'm facing is that I need to open another connection using sockets and send the response 'live' over this connection while httpwebresponse is still receiving. I get extra garbage data (doubled ending) so if I knew actual body length beforehand, I would know how many bytes to read.

Comment: @user1015551: Are you *sure* you get "extra garbage data"? Are you sure you're not just ignoring the return value of `Stream.Read` and sending through the contents of your whole buffer even if the stream ended after the first byte? That would explain it. Please show us your code.

Comment: I updated my question, thanks! Can you explain in more detail what do you mean by ignoring value of Stream.Read? On the proxy side I use async sockets and read the whole incoming response stream from client into the buffer, then return it to the browser.

Comment: your call to responseStream.Read returns a value you save in your variable "count". That value says how many bytes the Read-function actually wrote to your byte-array. However, when you send the data on the next line of code you send the whole byte array. You should add a reference to your "count"-variable there. That's what @JonSkeet is talking about