# Length = 'requestStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, zendesk

I have consumed Zendesk rest apis to create the case and below is the peace of code

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXML);
DisputeResolutionEntity disputeResolutionEntity = new DisputeResolutionEntity();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["zendeskAdd"].ToString());
request.Method = "POST";
password = Clearshift.Registration.CommonFunction.DecryptString(password);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I found that "Length" and "Position" properties of "Stream" object is returning below the error:

> Length = 'requestStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Can anybody help?

Comment: Reference link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527316/how-to-set-the-content-of-an-httpwebrequest-in-c

Comment: Reference Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457907/httpwebrequest-invalid-contentlength

Comment: The request stream doesn't have a defined length, since you're the one writing to it. Anyway, in the code you posted, you're not accessing the Length or Position; why do you need to do that?

Comment: Because while hitting the "HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();" shows 404 error.

Comment: @JasonEvans: The same implementation I have done from which link you have provided.